# How to confirm if my answer has O(1) space complexity and in modification of an array? It is the Reverse a String Leetcode question

Tags: python, arrays, string, time-complexity, space-complexity

I was doing a problem on Leetcode - here is the problem:

**Write a function that reverses a string. The input string is given as an array of characters char[].
Do not allocate extra space for another array, you must do this by modifying the input array in-place with O(1) extra memory.
You may assume all the characters consist of printable ascii characters.**

My solution is

```
    def reverseString(s):
        """
        Do not return anything, modify s in-place instead.
        """
        
        temp = ""
        for index,value in enumerate(s):
            temp+=value
        
        s.clear()
        for i in "".join(reversed(temp)):
            s.append(i)
   
    reverseString(["h","e","l","l","o"])
```

My solution works and is accepted by Leetcode. It also passes all the test cases. However, I am still new to the concept of space and time and was not sure if my solution follows the requirements of O(1) and modifies the array in place. If someone could confirm if it does or not and also teach me how to confirm this, it would be helpful. Thank you!

Comment: It modifies the *list* in place, but it requires auxilliary memory, e.g. your `temp` string, and the string you use to iterate over `"".join(refersed(temp))`. It is not constant space. Also `"".join(reversed(temp))` requires a new string. It is also completely unnecessary, you could haeve just done `for i in reversed(temp):`

Comment: The problem is poorly defined.  It says *Do not allocate extra space for another array* but also requires your solution be O(1) in space, which **does** allow the allocation of extra space.

Comment: @Tumbleweed53 they are trying to get you to do a sort of classic "reverse the array in constant space" solution.

Comment: BTW, using `reversed` here defeats the spirit of this exercise, might as well just do `s.reverse()` and leave it at that if you are going to use `reversed`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga due to the way the Python language defines strings as immutable, it's essentially impossible to reverse in place (of course, a given Python implementation may be clever enough to use no extra memory).

Comment: @Tumbleweed53 the OP's input is a *list*. The problem here is that the OP is providing the instructions from one of these coding challanges websites, which often write the question once geared towards a language like C ("The input string is given as an array of characters char[]."). But *there are no arrays of char in Python*. Well, there are if you use the `array` module, but they are getting an input which is a *list of strings*.

Comment: @Tumbleweed53 This a algorithm qustion, it inspect the respondent   the algorithm thought, do not inspect the understand of a language for how the language  use the memory. So you two just got the wrong direct for the core aim the qustion given. The space-complexity is about the space which respondent defined and used for his resolution

Comment: Actually you use the function `reversed` in python to reverse the string is likely a little bit of cheating. But you really finish the work by achiving the goal and  to define and use countable memory which asked O(1) space-complexity. Strictly speaking the answer is not good.

Answer (score 0):

O(1) means you use extra constant memory of variables to solve the question. To be opposed, the extra memory of variabels you used related to the question's data size. E.g, the size of string array which want you to reverse is x,you use y=ax+b memory of variables means O(n). y=ax^2+bx+c means O(n^2). Do you get it?

Comment: Actually, there's a O(0) way to reverse a string I remenber, which is use XOR with letters can exchange their position.

Comment: "O(1) means you use constant number of variables to solve the question." wrong. That isn't what O(1) means at all. The number of variable is irrelevant.

Comment: Use the binary(or ascii) for two lettlers (the front and the back letter) to calc, (C language is:)a = a^b; b = a^b; a = a^b;

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga This is my simple understand and easy way to explain it. So what you understand about the space-complexity, show me your explaination for learning.

Comment: The number of variables is *irrelevant* it is about the extra *memory* you use. Variables don't matter. Here is an algorithm that uses a constant amount of variables to reverse a list: `list(reversed(my_list))` and yet, it is not constant memory at all. As for the definition of time and space complexity, it is the *asymptotic*, limiting behavior of an algorithm in terms of its inputs (where we can consider either it's runtime or memory requirements).

Comment: The nature of your explanation isn't the problem, intuitive definitions are fine, you don't need to explain everything in a rigorously, mathematical way to be useful, but it's that you are talking about *variables*. Variables don't matter here. It's the wrong consideration

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga So I fix my answer to the variable used memory. I just want to explain it easily for understand it, so that just equal variable to space(memroy).

Comment: O(1) just means you use a constant amount of memory.  You can use as many variables as you want as long as they refer to the already allocated memory.  Your fix didn't actually fix anything.

Comment: @Donnied OK, fix again, maybe it's clearly for you guys, but maybe not easy for beginner. Anyway it is my fault not to be strick by ignoring the different.

Comment: I don't think much about the essence of space, before all upstairs remind it, I just explain it so rash. I got a deeply thinking about it. It's necessary for beginner to follow the right opinion from the begin. Thankx for all.

Comment: To cover a hole but dig a new one is not good.

Comment: @Donnie That's not true at all. Firstly, declaring n variables (= pointers) referencing already allocated memory will take O(n) space. Secondly, declaring one variable and assigning to it a new array of constant length 1000000 is still O(1).

Comment: Really great discussion here! So just to understand, if I declare a variable to hold values of a list supposedly while I'm iterating through it.  It would still be O(n) since the variable is holding the data of the len of the list?

Comment: @dexter27 Yeah. For more if you use double len like 2*n space, it still is O(n).Untill you use n*n, it's O(n^2).According to upstairs, you must get the space and memory metric for  space complexity, not the number of variables.